# Replace function `\` error in the javascript

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I have a problem with the string symbol error, I want replace this symbol `\`, but it doesn't work. My sample code javascript like below the coding:

I am doing below this testing, cannot alert the message

```js
var file_name = "C:\fakepath\claim 20210121 1754.sql";
var bbb = file_name.replace("C:\fakepath", "123");
alert(bbb);
```

If below the javascript code without `\` , it can replace, the alert message is `123\fakepath\claim 20210121 1754.sql`:

```js
var file_name = "C:\fakepath\claim 20210121 1754.sql";
var bbb = file_name.replace("C:", "123");
alert(bbb);
```

Actually I want the alert message result is `123\claim 20210121 1754.sql`

Comment: Try `file_name.replace("C:\\fakepath", "123");` with 2 backslashes

Comment: Windows allows you to use forward slashes as directory separators. That will make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash begins escape sequences, you need to double them to make them literal.

```js
var file_name = "C:\\fakepath\\claim 20210121 1754.sql";
var bbb = file_name.replace("C:\\fakepath", "123");
alert(bbb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the escape character (`\`) by doubling (`\\`) it:

```js
const file_name = "C:\fakepath\claim 20210121 1754.sql"
const bbb = file_name.replace("C:\fakepath", "123\\")
const p = document.querySelector('pre')
p.innerText += bbb
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Output:

```
123\claim 20210121 1754.sql
```